# How to get and update Primefaces pickList bean source and target lists via javascript

Tags: javascript, primefaces, interaction

Im developing a map application that has select interaction.  Trying to update pickList bean when cities selected.

```
<script>  
function onCitySelected(e) {  

   // get myPrimeFacesPickList

   // update myPrimeFacesPickList : move e.selectedCity source to target 
}  
</script>
```

Are there any way to get and update source and target City lists in my javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a primeface [RemoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf)

It will add a js function to your page that you can use inside your `onCitySelected` function. Calling the function will then trigger a method in your backing bean in which you can add the selected city to your model (using `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`) and then update your pickList by setting the id of the list in the `update` attribute of the `remoteCommand`.

Check out the [show case for remoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) in the primefaces showcase and also consult the [primefaces documentation](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf) on the remoteCommand component.